# how to properly handle touch events for multiple layers?

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

I currently have a "Console" CClayer, which is handling touch detection for sprites that have been added to it.  However, I also have some sprites that I want to do touch detection on that are not part of the Console layer...  They are currently children of a class that inherits from CCNode.

My understanding is, the more cocos objects have the "isTouchEnabled" property set to true, the more performance will be affected, so I am curious how I should approach this?

Should I:

A)  Have the console's touchesBegan method perform detection of the sprites belonging to the CCNode?

B)  Just implement isTouchEnabled on the CCNode object

C)  Some other approach?

Answer (score 0):

well, for starters, you should only concern yourself about performance if you are concerned i.e. you are seeing or measuring (on DEVICES not a simulator) some inappropriate response times.

I would avoid detecting touches that concern another node - it could get messy, software wise. I tend to return YES (from a ccTouchBegan) strictly when the touch is at a location of an object of concern to the detecting node. When you return NO, the dispatcher will pass on the touch to other handlers ('under' the console), until one such CCNode takes the bite. Kind of as follows:

```
- (void) onEnter{
    [[[CCDirector sharedDirector] touchDispatcher] addTargetedDelegate:self priority:0 swallowsTouches:YES];
    [super onEnter];
}

- (void) onExit{
    [[[CCDirector sharedDirector] touchDispatcher] removeDelegate:self];
[super onExit];
}

- (BOOL)ccTouchBegan:(UITouch *)touch withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
    if (!_visible || !_enabled) {
        return NO;
    }
    CGPoint loc = [touch locationInView:touch.view];
    loc = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] convertToGL:loc];

    if ([self containsPoint:loc]) {
        // do your thing here !
        return YES;
    }

    return NO;
}

-(BOOL) containsPoint:(CGPoint) location {
    // determine here whether this node should be handling
    // this touch.
}
```

Comment: So you don't use touchBegan on the parent object, and check for touches in the children sprites?  You actually do touchBegan on the individual sprites themselves?

Comment: Actually i use a touch handling protocol where it makes sense to do so in the game. The above is from a home grown scrolling menu. In a tile-based RPG, for gameplay i have 2 touch handlers : one for the WorldView handler : it knows where all the soldiers are, what tiles are, and what 'touch sensitive' objects lay on the map. The other is for my HumanController object, basically the GUI for selecting skills and moves, etc... I dont typically subclass CCSprite : instead i have a Soldier class with a mapLayout handler. It decides how to represent the soldier and uses services of the WorldView.